# Using a Temporary table kills the queryplan

Tags: postgresql, temp-tables

Hi i have a query with an IN clause. The IN-List can be verry large so i'm creating a temporary table first, but this breaks my query plan and takes uneccessary long time.

With temptable

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempcards (cardid bigint) ON COMMIT DROP;
INSERT INTO tempcards (cardid) VALUES (204313100);


EXPLAIN SELECT 
count(*)
 FROM filecardentity sourcecard
 INNER JOIN lessonentity ON (sourcelesson_lessonid = sourcecard.lesson_lessonid) 
 INNER JOIN assignmentdelivery ON (assignmentdelivery.assignment_id = lessonentity.assignment_id)
 --LEFT JOIN filecardentity targetcard ON (targetcard.original_cardid = sourcecard.cardid AND targetcard.assignment_id = lessonentity.assignment_id) 
 WHERE sourcecard.cardid IN (SELECT cardid FROM tempcards) 

"Aggregate  (cost=2006601.72..2006601.73 rows=1 width=0)"
"  ->  Merge Join  (cost=949476.63..1820711.11 rows=74356243 width=0)"
"        Merge Cond: (sourcecard.lesson_lessonid = lessonentity.sourcelesson_lessonid)"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=673658.21..688573.90 rows=5966274 width=8)"
"              Sort Key: sourcecard.lesson_lessonid"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=36.75..2201.84 rows=5966274 width=8)"
"                    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=36.75..38.75 rows=200 width=8)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on tempcards  (cost=0.00..31.40 rows=2140 width=8)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using filecardentity_pkey on filecardentity sourcecard  (cost=0.00..10.81 rows=1 width=16)"
"                          Index Cond: (cardid = tempcards.cardid)"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=275803.27..280152.44 rows=1739667 width=8)"
"              Sort Key: lessonentity.sourcelesson_lessonid"
"              ->  Merge Join  (cost=74428.81..95483.48 rows=1739667 width=8)"
"                    Merge Cond: (assignmentdelivery.assignment_id = lessonentity.assignment_id)"
"                    ->  Index Only Scan using fk_fk11c5a601f3011b4_idx on assignmentdelivery  (cost=0.00..1374.42 rows=51344 width=8)"
"                    ->  Sort  (cost=74402.44..75901.33 rows=599555 width=16)"
"                          Sort Key: lessonentity.assignment_id"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on lessonentity  (cost=0.00..16864.55 rows=599555 width=16)"
```

=>800ms

without temp table

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
count(*)
 FROM filecardentity sourcecard
 INNER JOIN lessonentity ON (sourcelesson_lessonid = sourcecard.lesson_lessonid) 
 INNER JOIN assignmentdelivery ON (assignmentdelivery.assignment_id = lessonentity.assignment_id)
 --LEFT JOIN filecardentity targetcard ON (targetcard.original_cardid = sourcecard.cardid AND targetcard.assignment_id = lessonentity.assignment_id) 
 WHERE sourcecard.cardid IN (204313100) 

"Aggregate  (cost=274.15..274.16 rows=1 width=0)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..274.12 rows=12 width=0)"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..263.02 rows=4 width=8)"
"              ->  Index Scan using filecardentity_pkey on filecardentity sourcecard  (cost=0.00..10.87 rows=1 width=8)"
"                    Index Cond: (cardid = 204313100)"
"              ->  Index Scan using fk_fka046075b829910ba_idx on lessonentity  (cost=0.00..251.42 rows=73 width=16)"
"                    Index Cond: (sourcelesson_lessonid = sourcecard.lesson_lessonid)"
"        ->  Index Only Scan using fk_fk11c5a601f3011b4_idx on assignmentdelivery  (cost=0.00..2.77 rows=1 width=8)"
"              Index Cond: (assignment_id = lessonentity.assignment_id)"
```

=>55ms

Comment: no already tried this

Comment: Can you do an `explain analyze` and post those plans?

Comment: whereupon.. just tried it again and it helped

Comment: The database has no statistics about the temp table, you have to analyze it first and then execute your query. But, why do you think a temp table would be faster than using the input directly in a single query? You could also use a CTE to avoid the temp table.

Comment: yes but sometimes it must contain 5000 or more ids which leads to a too long query string

Comment: IN() isn't optimal when having 5000+ parameters, performance will be bad. Try EXISTS, works much better, and give the CTE also a try to avoid overhead in creating a temp table.

Comment: how could i make an exist without the temp table? The ids come from a client, i can't select them from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using a CTE and EXISTS:

```
WITH input AS (
    -- the string '1,2,3,4' can be your input from the client
    SELECT unnest(string_to_array('1,2,3,4', ',')::int[]) AS id -- just an example for the input
)
SELECT  * 
FROM    foo 
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT  42  -- just something
    FROM    input   -- your cte or temp table if you don't use a cte at all
    WHERE   input.id = foo -- the "join"
);
```

If you still want to / have to use a temp table, just drop the first (WITH) part of the query and change the EXISTS to use your temp table.

The input in this example is a comma separated string containing integers, without spaces.